# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near'check (id

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

While creating a table I'm getting following error

```
create table check(
id int(9) auto_increment,
test_case varchar(20),
file_name varchar(200),
coverage int(5),
primary key(test_case,file_name));
```

As I'm getting following error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use 
near 'check( id int(9) auto_increment,test_case varchar(20),file_name 
varchar(200),cov' at line 1
```

Comment: `check` is a reserved word on MySQL. Simply rename your table and all should be fine.

Comment: thanks its worked fine

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 (possibly 3) errors, 1 Check is a reserved word either change it or enclose it in backticks, 2 id is auto_increment and must be defined as primary key, 3 defined  primary is invalid because id has to be primary key.

```
create table `check`(
id int(9) auto_increment primary key,
test_case varchar(20),
file_name varchar(200),
coverage int(5),
 key k1(test_case,file_name));
```

Comment: It should still be unique